# Removing Android Auto - is not recognized by Google Play console

Tags: java, android, google-play-console, android-auto

The release of my media app (new feature support `Android Auto`) is rejected cause "
Not adhering to Android Auto App Quality Requirements policy".

Now, I have removed `Android Auto` from the `manifest.xml` and published a version **without** `Android Auto`, but Google still refuses any update with the above reason (even if there is no `Android Auto` in the app anymore).

How can I remove `Android Auto` to release new versions of my app?

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: Make sure to update also any test tracks (e.g. beta) if you also used the Android Auto builds there.

Comment: @Derek K: please post your comment as an answer, then i can accept it as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to update also any test tracks (e.g. beta) if you also used the Android Auto builds there. It's important to keep testing tracks updated and compliant with their policies or disable them if no longer used. This helps to avoid confusion in the future when you get unexpected app removal or rejection.